# UIPanGestureRecognizer on a Custom View never called

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, uigesturerecognizer

I m using `Xamarin` for `iOS` and I have a custom view (inherit from `UIView`), And I try to add a simple `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, see this:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer panGesture = new UIPanGestureRecognizer (() => Console.WriteLine ("Pan");
this.AddGestureRecognizer(panGesture);
```

But "Pan" never shown in the console :/

Again, I have a custom view.

***Edit:***
When I move my code:

```
UIView myView = new UIView (new RectangleF(0,0,200,200));
myView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
myView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;    

var recognizer = new UIPanGestureRecognizer ((g) => {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Panning detected");
                    Console.WriteLine ("Gesture recognizer state: {0}", g.State);
                });

myView.AddGestureRecognizer (recognizer);
```

AddSubview (myView);
To the `UIVIewController` this works :///// why???

Should I do something with the `UIGestureDelegate`?!

Answer (score 1):

also you have to add below things.

Objective C:

```
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
```

Set this thing according to Xamarin syntax.

Also try this.

```
var panGesture = new UIPanGestureRecognizer (() => Console.WriteLine ("Pan");
this.view.AddGestureRecognizer(panGesture);
```

See below link for Updated Pangesture in Xamarin.

http://www.slideshare.net/Xamarin/whats-new-in-xamarinios-miguel

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. Second, R u sure?! Because I can't set this values...

Comment: yes you have to set this value so that panRecognizer know when it have to start work :)

Comment: But the Documentation says it by default 1 :/

Comment: Anyway, I can't set this properties... Any using/import?

Comment: Each view can handle multiple gesture recognizes.  Number of touches is the number of fingers to detect.

Comment: I think you replace "this.AddGestureRecognizer(panGesture);" to "this.view.AddGestureRecognizer(panGesture);"

Comment: But `this` is `UIView` by inheritance

Comment: refer this may be help you http://www.slideshare.net/Xamarin/whats-new-in-xamarinios-miguel

Comment: Thanks m8, but it didn't help :/